# Is there any ways to deploy desktop apps without using any third party database software like mysql or sql or others?

Tags: java, database

I am creating a java desktop application that uses database.And now i have to deploy its .exe to my friend's computer.Do i really have to install database software in my friend's computer?

Comment: If you use a database, you have to somehow *have* a database. You could use an embedded one if that makes sense.

Comment: Java doesn't compile to native ".exe" file. Java is platform independent and a ".exe" file is specific to the Windows platform. However, you can use a tool like JSmooth to wrap the Java ".jar" file in an exe

Comment: alternatively you can lend a server at a webhoster and connect your friends PCs to that remote database. of cause this requires internet access at the programs runtime.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions...I am pretty interested on using an embedded database...Sir would you mind to give me some ideas about it?
And can the database hold any amount of records that can be inserted?

Comment: anyone plz help me...@chrylis